# Как разделить список на отдельные списки с условием?

Tags: python, алгоритм, сортировка, list

Имеется список:

```
mas = ['1. Химия', '2. Индивидуальный проект', '3. Математика', '4. История', '5. Основы безопасности жизнедеятельности', '6. Методика решения математических задач повышенной сложности (внеурочная деятельность)', 
'7. Родной (русский) язык', '1. Классный час и ПДД', '2. Физика', '3. Русский язык', '4. Литература', '5. Математика', '6. Математика', '7. Английский язык', '8. Информатика', '1. Математика', '2. Английский язык',
 '3. Информатика', '4. История', '5. Практическое черчение', '6. Говорим и пишем правильно (внеурочная деятельность)', '7. Обществознание', '8. Астрономия', '1. Физика', '2. Английский язык', '3. Информатика',
 '4. Математика', '5. Математика', '6. Литература', '7. Физическая культура', '8. Физическая культура', '1. Физика', '2. Физика', '3. Литература', '4. Обществознание', '5. Практикум по физике', '6. Информатика']
```

Мне нужно разделить этот список на другие списки таким образом, чтобы в каждом отдельном списке были подходящие по дням уроки. К примеру, должно получится так:

```
[
    ['1. Химия', '2. Индивидуальный проект', '3. Математика', '4. История', '5. Основы безопасности жизнедеятельности', '6. Методика решения математических задач повышенной сложности (внеурочная деятельность)', '7. Родной (русский) язык'],
    ['1. Классный час и ПДД', '2. Физика', '3. Русский язык', '4. Литература', '5. Математика', '6. Математика', '7. Английский язык', '8. Информатика']
]
```

Возможно ли это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

черновой, но рабочий вариант:

```
num_last = 0
day = []
new_mas = []

for m in mas:
    num = int(m.split('.')[0])

    if num > num_last:
        day.append(m)
    else:
        new_mas.append(day)
        day = [m]

    num_last = num

new_mas.append(day)
```

в `new_mas`:

```
[
    ['1. Химия', '2. Индивидуальный проект', '3. Математика', '4. История', '5. Основы безопасности жизнедеятельности', '6. Методика решения математических задач повышенной сложности (внеурочная деятельность)', '7. Родной (русский) язык'], 
    ['1. Классный час и ПДД', '2. Физика', '3. Русский язык', '4. Литература', '5. Математика', '6. Математика', '7. Английский язык', '8. Информатика'], 
    ['1. Математика', '2. Английский язык', '3. Информатика', '4. История', '5. Практическое черчение', '6. Говорим и пишем правильно (внеурочная деятельность)', '7. Обществознание', '8. Астрономия'], 
    ['1. Физика', '2. Английский язык', '3. Информатика', '4. Математика', '5. Математика', '6. Литература', '7. Физическая культура', '8. Физическая культура'],
    ['1. Физика', '2. Физика', '3. Литература', '4. Обществознание', '5. Практикум по физике', '6. Информатика']
]
```

Comment: работает, но последний день не выводит, у меня такая-же проблема была

Comment: @wensiet точно, последний день не приаппендил... исправил

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
res = []

for el in mas:
    if el.startswith('1.'):
        res.append([])
    res[-1].append(el)

print(res)
```

Comment: да, супер! лаконично и без лишних телодвижений